# Brother printer margin problem Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: printing

Our Brother DCP585CW printer decreases top-margins and increases bottom-margins. Noticed this with paper-sizes A4, A5 and A6.
Same documents printed to same printer from OSX or windows10 does not have this.

How can i solve it?

This is the ppd-file:

```
*PPD-Adobe: "4.3"

*%================================================
*%  Copyright(C) 2006 Brother Industries, Ltd.
*%  "Brother DCP-585CW CUPS"
*%================================================

*%==== General Information Keywords ========================
*FormatVersion: "4.3"
*FileVersion: "1.00"
*LanguageVersion: English
*LanguageEncoding: ISOLatin1
*PCFileName: "BR585_2.PPD"
*Manufacturer: "Brother"
*Product: "(DCP-585CW)"
*1284DeviceID: "MFG:Brother;MDL:DCP-585CW"
*cupsVersion: 1.1
*cupsManualCopies: False
*cupsFilter: "application/vnd.cups-postscript 0 brlpdwrapperdcp585cw"
*cupsModelNumber: 8
*ModelName: "Brother DCP-585CW"
*ShortNickName: "Brother DCP-585CW"
*NickName: "Brother DCP-585CW CUPS v1.1"
*PSVersion: "(3010.106) 3"

*%==== Basic Device Capabilities =============
*LanguageLevel: "3"
*ColorDevice: True
*DefaultColorSpace: RGB
*FileSystem: False
*Throughput: "12"
*LandscapeOrientation: Plus90
*VariablePaperSize: False
*TTRasterizer: Type42
*FreeVM: "1700000"

*%DefaultOutputOrder: Reverse

*%==== UI Constraints ======================

*%==== Media Selection ======================
*OpenUI *PageSize/Media Size: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 11 AnySetup *PageSize
*DefaultPageSize: A4
*PageSize A4/A4:                    "          "
*PageSize BrA4_B/A4 (Borderless):           "          "
*PageSize Letter/Letter:                "          "
*PageSize BrLetter_B/US Letter (Borderless):        "          "
*PageSize Legal/Legal:              "          "
*PageSize Executive/Executive:          "          "
*PageSize B5/JIS B5:                "          "
*PageSize A5/A5:                    "          "
*PageSize A6/A6:                    "          "
*PageSize BrA6_B/A6 (Borderless):           "          "
*PageSize PostC4x6/Photo:               "          "
*PageSize BrPostC4x6_B/Photo (Borderless):      "          "
*PageSize IndexC5x8/Index Card:         "          "
*PageSize BrIndexC5x8_B/Index Card (Borderless):    "          "
*PageSize PhotoL/Photo L:               "          "
*PageSize BrPhotoL_B/Photo L (Borderless):      "          "
*PageSize Photo2L/Photo 2L:                 "          "
*PageSize BrPhoto2L_B/Photo 2L (Borderless):        "          "
*PageSize Postcard/Postcard 1:              "          "
*PageSize BrHagaki_B/Postcard 1 (Borderless):       "          "
*PageSize DoublePostcardRotated/Postcard 2 (Double):        "          "
*PageSize EnvC5/C5 Envelope:                "          "
*PageSize EnvDL/DL Envelope:                "          "
*PageSize Env10/Com-10:             "          "
*PageSize EnvMonarch/Monarch:               "          "
*PageSize EnvYou4/JE4 Envelope:             "          "
*CloseUI: *PageSize

*OpenUI *PageRegion: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 12 AnySetup *PageRegion
*DefaultPageRegion: A4
*PageRegion A4/A4:                  "          "
*PageRegion BrA4_B/A4 (Borderless):         "          "
*PageRegion Letter/Letter:              "          "
*PageRegion BrLetter_B/US Letter (Borderless):      "          "
*PageRegion Legal/Legal:                "          "
*PageRegion Executive/Executive:            "          "
*PageRegion B5/JIS B5:              "          "
*PageRegion A5/A5:                  "          "
*PageRegion A6/A6:                  "          "
*PageRegion BrA6_B/A6 (Borderless):         "          "
*PageRegion PostC4x6/Photo:             "          "
*PageRegion BrPostC4x6_B/Photo (Borderless):        "          "
*PageRegion IndexC5x8/Index Card:           "          "
*PageRegion BrIndexC5x8_B/Index Card (Borderless):  "          "
*PageRegion PhotoL/Photo L:                 "          "
*PageRegion BrPhotoL_B/Photo L (Borderless):        "          "
*PageRegion Photo2L/Photo 2L:           "          "
*PageRegion BrPhoto2L_B/Photo 2L (Borderless):      "          "
*PageRegion Postcard/Postcard 1:            "          "
*PageRegion BrHagaki_B/Postcard 1 (Borderless):     "          "
*PageRegion DoublePostcardRotated/Postcard 2 (Double):      "          "
*PageRegion EnvC5/C5 Envelope:              "          "
*PageRegion EnvDL/DL Envelope:              "          "
*PageRegion Env10/Com-10:               "          "
*PageRegion EnvMonarch/Monarch:             "          "
*PageRegion EnvYou4/JE4 Envelope:           "          "
*CloseUI: *PageRegion

*DefaultImageableArea: A4
*ImageableArea A4/A4:                   "9 9 576 820"
*ImageableArea BrA4_B/A4 (Borderless):          "6 6 595  839"
*ImageableArea Letter/Letter:               "9 9 593 770"
*ImageableArea BrLetter_B/US Letter (Borderless):       "9 9 615 792"
*ImageableArea Legal/Legal:             "9 9 593 986"
*ImageableArea Executive/Executive:         "9 9 503 734"
*ImageableArea B5/JIS B5:               "9 9 481 687"
*ImageableArea A5/A5:                   "9 9 401 573"
*ImageableArea A6/A6:                   "9 9 279 397"
*ImageableArea BrA6_B/A6 (Borderless):          "6 6 296 424"
*ImageableArea PostC4x6/Photo:          "9 9 269 410"
*ImageableArea BrPostC4x6_B/Photo (Borderless):     "6 6 285 436"
*ImageableArea IndexC5x8/Index Card:            "9 9 341 554"
*ImageableArea BrIndexC5x8_B/Index Card (Borderless):   "6 6 357 580"
*ImageableArea PhotoL/Photo L:          "9 9 233 338"
*ImageableArea BrPhotoL_B/Photo L (Borderless):     "6 6 251 364"
*ImageableArea Photo2L/Photo 2L:            "9 9 340 483"
*ImageableArea BrPhoto2L_B/Photo 2L (Borderless):   "6 6 357 509"
*ImageableArea Postcard/Postcard 1:             "9 9 264 397"
*ImageableArea BrHagaki_B/Postcard 1 (Borderless):  "6 6 280 423"
*ImageableArea DoublePostcardRotated/Postcard 2 (Double):   "9 9 401 545"
*ImageableArea EnvC5/C5 Envelope:           "9 68 440 686"
*ImageableArea EnvDL/DL Envelope:           "9 68 293 661"
*ImageableArea Env10/Com-10:                "9 68 275 721"
*ImageableArea EnvMonarch/Monarch:          "9 68 260 577"
*ImageableArea EnvYou4/JE4 Envelope:            "9 68 278 701"

*%==== Information About Media Sizes ========
*DefaultPaperDimension: A4
*PaperDimension A4/A4:              "585 829"
*PaperDimension BrA4_B/A4 (Borderless):         "601 845"
*PaperDimension Letter/Letter:          "602 779"
*PaperDimension BrLetter_B/US Letter (Borderless):      "624 801"
*PaperDimension Legal/Legal:                "602 995"
*PaperDimension Executive/Executive:            "612 743"
*PaperDimension B5/JIS B5:              "490 696"
*PaperDimension A5/A5:              "410 582"
*PaperDimension A6/A6:              "288 406"
*PaperDimension BrA6_B/A6 (Borderless):         "302 430"
*PaperDimension PostC4x6/Photo:         "278 419"
*PaperDimension BrPostC4x6_B/Photo (Borderless):    "291 442"
*PaperDimension IndexC5x8/Index Card:           "350 563"
*PaperDimension BrIndexC5x8_B/Index Card (Borderless):  "363 586"
*PaperDimension PhotoL/Photo L:         "242 347"
*PaperDimension BrPhotoL_B/Photo L (Borderless):    "257 370"
*PaperDimension Photo2L/Photo 2L:           "349 492"
*PaperDimension BrPhoto2L_B/Photo 2L (Borderless):  "363 515"
*PaperDimension Postcard/Postcard 1:            "273 406"
*PaperDimension BrHagaki_B/Postcard 1 (Borderless): "286 429"
*PaperDimension DoublePostcardRotated/Postcard 2 (Double):  "410 554"
*PaperDimension EnvC5/C5 Envelope:          "449 720"
*PaperDimension EnvDL/DL Envelope:          "302 695"
*PaperDimension Env10/Com-10:               "284 755"
*PaperDimension EnvMonarch/Monarch:         "269 611"
*PaperDimension EnvYou4/JE4 Envelope:           "287 735"

*%==== Custom Page Sizes ====================
*NonUIOrderDependency: 40 AnySetup *CustomPageSize
*VariablePaperSize: True
*LeadingEdge Short: ""
*MaxMediaWidth: "612"
*MaxMediaHeight: "1008"
*HWMargins: 8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5
*CustomPageSize True: "          "
*End
*ParamCustomPageSize Width: 1 points 252 612
*ParamCustomPageSize Height: 2 points 360 1008
*ParamCustomPageSize WidthOffset: 3 points 0 0
*ParamCustomPageSize HeightOffset: 4 points 0 0
*ParamCustomPageSize Orientation: 5 int 0 3

*%=== Paper Feed================================

*%==== Resolution Features =================================
*OpenUI *Resolution/Quality: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 14 AnySetup *Resolution
*DefaultResolution: 600x600dpi
*Resolution 150x150dpi/Fast:    "          "
*Resolution 300x300dpi/Fast Normal:     "          "
*Resolution 600x600dpi/Normal:      "          "
*Resolution 1200x1200dpi/Fine:      "          "
*Resolution 1200x2400dpi/Photo:         "          "
*Resolution 1200x6000dpi/Highest:   "          "
*CloseUI: *Resolution

*%=== MonoOrColor ================================
*OpenUI *BRMonoColor/Color/Grayscale: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 15 AnySetup *BRMonoColor
*DefaultBRMonoColor: Color
*BRMonoColor Color/Color: ""
*BRMonoColor Mono/Grayscale: ""
*CloseUI: *BRMonoColor

*%=== SlowDrying ================================
*OpenUI *BRSlowDrying/Slow Drying Paper: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 31 AnySetup *BRSlowDrying
*DefaultBRSlowDrying: OFF
*BRSlowDrying OFF/OFF: ""
*BRSlowDrying ON/ON: ""
*CloseUI: *BRSlowDrying

*%=== Media Type ================================
*OpenUI *BRColorMediaType/Media Type: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 16 AnySetup *BRColorMediaType
*DefaultBRColorMediaType: Plain
*BRColorMediaType Plain/Plain Paper: "          "
*BRColorMediaType Inkjet/Inkjet Paper: "          "
*BRColorMediaType BrotherGlossyR/Brother BP71 Photo Paper: "          "
*BRColorMediaType BrotherGlossy/Brother BP61 Photo Paper: "          "
*BRColorMediaType Glossy/Other Photo Paper: "          "
*BRColorMediaType Transparencies/Transparencies: "          "
*%BRColorMediaType HagakiAtena: "          "
*%BRColorMediaType HagakiUra: "          "
*CloseUI: *BRColorMediaType

*%=== Paper Thick ================================
*OpenUI *BRColorPaperThick/Paper Thickness: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 17 AnySetup *BRColorPaperThick
*DefaultBRColorPaperThick: Regular
*BRColorPaperThick Regular/Regular: ""
*BRColorPaperThick Thick/Thick: ""
*CloseUI: *BRColorPaperThick

*%=== Bi-DirKey ================================
*OpenUI *BRBiDir/Bi-Directional Printing: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 18 AnySetup *BRColorPaperThick
*DefaultBRBiDir: ON
*BRBiDir OFF/OFF: ""
*BRBiDir ON/ON: ""
*CloseUI: *BRBiDir

*%=== Reverse Printing ================================
*OpenUI *BRReverse/Reverse Printing: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 19 AnySetup *BRReverse
*DefaultBRReverse: OFF
*BRReverse OFF/OFF: ""
*BRReverse ON/ON: ""
*CloseUI: *BRReverse

*%=== Mirror Printing ================================
*OpenUI *BrMirror/Mirror Printing: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 20 AnySetup *BrMirror
*DefaultBrMirror: OFF
*BrMirror OFF/OFF: "          "
*BrMirror ON/ON: "          "
*CloseUI: *BrMirror

*%=== Jpeg Printing ================================
*OpenUI *BRJpeg/Data Transfer Mode: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 22 AnySetup *BRJpeg
*DefaultBRJpeg: Recommended
*BRJpeg Recommended/Recommended Setting: ""
*BRJpeg QualityPrior/Improved Print Quality: ""
*BRJpeg SpeedPrior/Improved Print Speed: ""
*CloseUI: *BRJpeg

*OpenGroup:Image Type
*%=== Color Mode ================================
*OpenUI *BRColorMatching/Color Mode: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 21 AnySetup *BRColorMatching
*DefaultBRColorMatching: Natural
*BRColorMatching Natural/Natural: ""
*BRColorMatching Vivid/Vivid: ""
*BRColorMatching None/None: ""
*CloseUI: *BRColorMatching

*%=== Half Tone Pattern ================================
*OpenUI *BRHalfTonePattern/Halftone Pattern: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 23 AnySetup * BRHalfTonePattern
*DefaultBRHalfTonePattern: Diffusion
*BRHalfTonePattern Diffusion/Diffusion: ""
*BRHalfTonePattern Dither/Dither: ""
*CloseUI: *BRHalfTonePattern

*CloseGroup:Image Type

*OpenGroup:Color Enhancement
*%=== True2Life ================================
*OpenUI *BRColorEnhancement/     Color Enhancement(True2Life): PickOne
*OrderDependency: 24 AnySetup *BRColorEnhancement
*DefaultBRColorEnhancement: OFF
*BRColorEnhancement OFF/OFF: ""
*BRColorEnhancement ON/ON: ""
*CloseUI: *BRColorEnhancement

*%=== Brightness ================================
*OpenUI *BRBrightness/    Brightness: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 25 AnySetup *BRBrightness
*DefaultBRBrightness: 0
*BRBrightness -20/-20: ""
*BRBrightness -19/-19: ""
*BRBrightness -18/-18: ""
*BRBrightness -17/-17: ""
*BRBrightness -16/-16: ""
*BRBrightness -15/-15: ""
*BRBrightness -14/-14: ""
*BRBrightness -13/-13: ""
*BRBrightness -12/-12: ""
*BRBrightness -11/-11: ""
*BRBrightness -10/-10: ""
*BRBrightness -9/-9: ""
*BRBrightness -8/-8: ""
*BRBrightness -7/-7: ""
*BRBrightness -6/-6: ""
*BRBrightness -5/-5: ""
*BRBrightness -4/-4: ""
*BRBrightness -3/-3: ""
*BRBrightness -2/-2: ""
*BRBrightness -1/-1: ""
*BRBrightness 0/0: ""
*BRBrightness 1/1: ""
*BRBrightness 2/2: ""
*BRBrightness 3/3: ""
*BRBrightness 4/4: ""
*BRBrightness 5/5: ""
*BRBrightness 6/6: ""
*BRBrightness 7/7: ""
*BRBrightness 8/8: ""
*BRBrightness 9/9: ""
*BRBrightness 10/10: ""
*BRBrightness 11/11: ""
*BRBrightness 12/12: ""
*BRBrightness 13/13: ""
*BRBrightness 14/14: ""
*BRBrightness 15/15: ""
*BRBrightness 16/16: ""
*BRBrightness 17/17: ""
*BRBrightness 18/18: ""
*BRBrightness 19/19: ""
*BRBrightness 20/20: ""
*CloseUI: *BRBrightness

*%=== Contrast ================================
*OpenUI *BRContrast/   Contrast: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 26 AnySetup *BRContrast
*DefaultBRContrast: 0
*BRContrast -20/-20: ""
*BRContrast -19/-19: ""
*BRContrast -18/-18: ""
*BRContrast -17/-17: ""
*BRContrast -16/-16: ""
*BRContrast -15/-15: ""
*BRContrast -14/-14: ""
*BRContrast -13/-13: ""
*BRContrast -12/-12: ""
*BRContrast -11/-11: ""
*BRContrast -10/-10: ""
*BRContrast -9/-9: ""
*BRContrast -8/-8: ""
*BRContrast -7/-7: ""
*BRContrast -6/-6: ""
*BRContrast -5/-5: ""
*BRContrast -4/-4: ""
*BRContrast -3/-3: ""
*BRContrast -2/-2: ""
*BRContrast -1/-1: ""
*BRContrast 0/0: ""
*BRContrast 1/1: ""
*BRContrast 2/2: ""
*BRContrast 3/3: ""
*BRContrast 4/4: ""
*BRContrast 5/5: ""
*BRContrast 6/6: ""
*BRContrast 7/7: ""
*BRContrast 8/8: ""
*BRContrast 9/9: ""
*BRContrast 10/10: ""
*BRContrast 11/11: ""
*BRContrast 12/12: ""
*BRContrast 13/13: ""
*BRContrast 14/14: ""
*BRContrast 15/15: ""
*BRContrast 16/16: ""
*BRContrast 17/17: ""
*BRContrast 18/18: ""
*BRContrast 19/19: ""
*BRContrast 20/20: ""
*CloseUI: *BRContrast

*%=== Red ================================
*OpenUI *BRRed/  Red: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 27 AnySetup *BRRed
*DefaultBRRed: 0
*BRRed -20/-20: ""
*BRRed -19/-19: ""
*BRRed -18/-18: ""
*BRRed -17/-17: ""
*BRRed -16/-16: ""
*BRRed -15/-15: ""
*BRRed -14/-14: ""
*BRRed -13/-13: ""
*BRRed -12/-12: ""
*BRRed -11/-11: ""
*BRRed -10/-10: ""
*BRRed -9/-9: ""
*BRRed -8/-8: ""
*BRRed -7/-7: ""
*BRRed -6/-6: ""
*BRRed -5/-5: ""
*BRRed -4/-4: ""
*BRRed -3/-3: ""
*BRRed -2/-2: ""
*BRRed -1/-1: ""
*BRRed 0/0: ""
*BRRed 1/1: ""
*BRRed 2/2: ""
*BRRed 3/3: ""
*BRRed 4/4: ""
*BRRed 5/5: ""
*BRRed 6/6: ""
*BRRed 7/7: ""
*BRRed 8/8: ""
*BRRed 9/9: ""
*BRRed 10/10: ""
*BRRed 11/11: ""
*BRRed 12/12: ""
*BRRed 13/13: ""
*BRRed 14/14: ""
*BRRed 15/15: ""
*BRRed 16/16: ""
*BRRed 17/17: ""
*BRRed 18/18: ""
*BRRed 19/19: ""
*BRRed 20/20: ""
*CloseUI: *BRRed

*%=== Green ================================
*OpenUI *BRGreen/ Green: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 28 AnySetup *BRGreen
*DefaultBRGreen: 0
*BRGreen -20/-20: ""
*BRGreen -19/-19: ""
*BRGreen -18/-18: ""
*BRGreen -17/-17: ""
*BRGreen -16/-16: ""
*BRGreen -15/-15: ""
*BRGreen -14/-14: ""
*BRGreen -13/-13: ""
*BRGreen -12/-12: ""
*BRGreen -11/-11: ""
*BRGreen -10/-10: ""
*BRGreen -9/-9: ""
*BRGreen -8/-8: ""
*BRGreen -7/-7: ""
*BRGreen -6/-6: ""
*BRGreen -5/-5: ""
*BRGreen -4/-4: ""
*BRGreen -3/-3: ""
*BRGreen -2/-2: ""
*BRGreen -1/-1: ""
*BRGreen 0/0: ""
*BRGreen 1/1: ""
*BRGreen 2/2: ""
*BRGreen 3/3: ""
*BRGreen 4/4: ""
*BRGreen 5/5: ""
*BRGreen 6/6: ""
*BRGreen 7/7: ""
*BRGreen 8/8: ""
*BRGreen 9/9: ""
*BRGreen 10/10: ""
*BRGreen 11/11: ""
*BRGreen 12/12: ""
*BRGreen 13/13: ""
*BRGreen 14/14: ""
*BRGreen 15/15: ""
*BRGreen 16/16: ""
*BRGreen 17/17: ""
*BRGreen 18/18: ""
*BRGreen 19/19: ""
*BRGreen 20/20: ""
*CloseUI: *BRGreen

*%=== Blue ================================
*OpenUI *BRBlue/Blue: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 29 AnySetup *BRBlue
*DefaultBRBlue: 0
*BRBlue -20/-20: ""
*BRBlue -19/-19: ""
*BRBlue -18/-18: ""
*BRBlue -17/-17: ""
*BRBlue -16/-16: ""
*BRBlue -15/-15: ""
*BRBlue -14/-14: ""
*BRBlue -13/-13: ""
*BRBlue -12/-12: ""
*BRBlue -11/-11: ""
*BRBlue -10/-10: ""
*BRBlue -9/-9: ""
*BRBlue -8/-8: ""
*BRBlue -7/-7: ""
*BRBlue -6/-6: ""
*BRBlue -5/-5: ""
*BRBlue -4/-4: ""
*BRBlue -3/-3: ""
*BRBlue -2/-2: ""
*BRBlue -1/-1: ""
*BRBlue 0/0: ""
*BRBlue 1/1: ""
*BRBlue 2/2: ""
*BRBlue 3/3: ""
*BRBlue 4/4: ""
*BRBlue 5/5: ""
*BRBlue 6/6: ""
*BRBlue 7/7: ""
*BRBlue 8/8: ""
*BRBlue 9/9: ""
*BRBlue 10/10: ""
*BRBlue 11/11: ""
*BRBlue 12/12: ""
*BRBlue 13/13: ""
*BRBlue 14/14: ""
*BRBlue 15/15: ""
*BRBlue 16/16: ""
*BRBlue 17/17: ""
*BRBlue 18/18: ""
*BRBlue 19/19: ""
*BRBlue 20/20: ""
*CloseUI: *BRBlue

*CloseGroup:Color Enhancement

*DefaultFont: Courier
*Font AvantGarde-Book: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font AvantGarde-BookOblique: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font AvantGarde-Demi: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font AvantGarde-DemiOblique: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-Demi: Standard "(001.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-DemiItalic: Standard "(001.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-Light: Standard "(001.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-LightItalic: Standard "(001.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier: Standard "(002.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier-Bold: Standard "(002.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier-BoldOblique: Standard "(002.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier-Oblique: Standard "(002.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Bold: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-BoldOblique: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow-Bold: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow-BoldOblique: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow-Oblique: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Oblique: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-Bold: Standard "(001.009S)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-BoldItalic: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-Italic: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-Roman: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-Bold: Standard "(001.005S)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-BoldItalic: Standard "(001.005S)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-Italic: Standard "(001.005S)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-Roman: Standard "(001.005S)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-Bold: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-BoldItalic: Standard "(001.009S)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-Italic: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-Roman: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font ZapfChancery-MediumItalic: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font ZapfDingbats: Special "(001.004S)" Special ROM
*Font Symbol: Special "(001.007S)" Special ROM
*Font Alaska: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font AlaskaExtrabold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font AntiqueOakland: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font AntiqueOakland-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font AntiqueOakland-Oblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font ClevelandCondensed: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Connecticut: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Guatemala-Antique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Guatemala-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Guatemala-Italic: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Guatemala-BoldItalic: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font LetterGothic: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font LetterGothic-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font LetterGothic-Oblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Maryland: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Oklahoma: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Oklahoma-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Oklahoma-Oblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Oklahoma-BoldOblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Utah: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Utah-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Utah-Oblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Utah-BoldOblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font UtahCondensed: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font UtahCondensed-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font UtahCondensed-Oblique: Standard "(001.004)" Standard ROM
*Font UtahCondensed-BoldOblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font BermudaScript: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Germany: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font SanDiego: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font US-Roman: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM

*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Plain *Resolution 1200x2400dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Plain *Resolution 1200x6000dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Inkjet    *Resolution 150x150dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Inkjet    *Resolution 300x300dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Inkjet    *Resolution 600x600dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Inkjet    *Resolution 1200x6000dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType BrotherGlossyR    *Resolution 150x150dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType BrotherGlossyR    *Resolution 300x300dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType BrotherGlossyR    *Resolution 600x600dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType BrotherGlossy *Resolution 150x150dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType BrotherGlossy *Resolution 300x300dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType BrotherGlossy *Resolution 600x600dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Glossy    *Resolution 150x150dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Glossy    *Resolution 300x300dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Glossy    *Resolution 600x600dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *Resolution 150x150dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *Resolution 300x300dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *Resolution 1200x2400dpi
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *Resolution 1200x6000dpi

*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *PageSize BrA4_B
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *PageSize BrLetter_B
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *PageSize BrA6_B
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *PageSize BrPostC4x6_B
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *PageSize BrIndexC5x8_B
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *PageSize BrPhotoL_B
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *PageSize BrPhoto2L_B
*UIConstraints: *BRColorMediaType Transparencies    *PageSize BrHagaki_B
```